# C# MVC Custom Routing Design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

With default route that is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{category}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

URL that is being generated looks like this: www.domain.com/Home/Index/Category

**But if user is browsing specific category I would like URL to look like this: www.domain.com/Home/Category**

**And if there is no category selected: www.domain.com/Home**

I added this code:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{category}", new { action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", category = (string)null });
```

and URL started to look the way I want it, but! Form method that calls action in the controller no longer works:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Home"))
                            {                
                                @Html.Hidden("category", Model.CurrentCategory)
                                @Html.Hidden("productId", p.ProductId)
                                <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" />
                            }
```

for some reason it seems like that form action method calls wrong route
that is:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{category}", new { action = "Index" });
```

and not

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", category = (string)null });
```

Because when submit button is clicked browser redirect to url: www.domain.com/Home/AddToCart and action method "AddToCart" in the "Home" controller is never called.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the MVC framework will go with the first route that matches. Which is:

```
     routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{category}", new { action = "Index" });
```

The routing mechanism cannot tell the difference between

```
     routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{category}", new { action = "Index" });
```

and

```
     routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", category = (string)null });
```

You need a route it like {controller}/Categories/{category} to match correctly. (if "Categories" don't bother you)

Another way is to use a regular expression as constrain to match the category names if the matching fails the routing falls to your second configuration so your form will continue to work.

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Comment: {controller}/Categories/{category} with code
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/Range/{category}", new { action = "Index" });  
routes.MapRoute("ShowAll", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });  
Works fine with most actions except, if I'm at www.domain.com/Home/Range/200-600
and have Html.ActionLink("Show All", "Index", "Home") the routing system redirect to www.domain.com/Home/Range/200-600 and not www.domain.com/Home/
but Html.ActionLink("Show All", "Index", "OtherController") works fine

Comment: I'm not sure why is not working for you. Maybe you post more code so I can have a better understanding. Or maybe you can figure your yourself why is not working by checking out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#routes

Comment: Can you provide the code for the action that handles this link Html.ActionLink("Show All", "Index", "Home")? Maybe you explicitly redirect in your code?

Comment: public ViewResult Index(string category)
        {
            ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
            {
                Products = products
                .Where(x => category == null || x.Category == category)
                .OrderBy(x => x.ProductId),
                CurrentCategory = category,
                Cart = GetCart()
            };           
            return View(viewModel);
        }

Comment: The code in action method seems to be correct. It has to be something related to your routes configurations. Check if its in correct order (most specific route to be first).